# How can I rename the "primary file" field's label in oracle ucm?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-ucm

I am trying to rename the "primary file" fields's label in a profile but don't know how to approach this. Is their any way to do this without changing the base js files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code (Git code snippet can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/jhult/G6GLb)) to a [rule side effect](https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2016/02/rule-side-effects-webcenter-content/):

```
<$std_set_primary_file_field_settings='
    <$include super.std_set_primary_file_field_settings$>

    <$fieldCaption = "This is the Primary File Caption"$>
'$>
<$setResourceInclude('std_set_primary_file_field_settings', std_set_primary_file_field_settings)$>
```

Make sure the rule executes on the checkin page. This takes [advantage of this technique](https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2015/09/dynamically-customize-webcenter-content-via-rule/).

Comment: Thankyou Jonathan, your code worked lika charm. Thankyou once again.